# Floating button over bottom sheet layout

Tags: android

I want to design a bottom sheet that will have a TextView ("Delete") and a floating button ('x') as shown:

[image]

How do I achieve this so that the 'x' appears over the TextView layout? I've tried different variations but they do not produce the result I want. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I found a lot of articles online that use FloatingButton over layouts but for some reason my output is always unexpected. I also found a similar question on stackoverflow, but the answer was not very helpful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672837/adjust-floating-button-position-in-relative-layout)

My bottom_sheet.xml layout code looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/delete_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background_primary">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/delete_container"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_24dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

but this just adds the floating button to the end (right) of the LinearLayout.

I also tried adding a marginTop to my LinearLayout so it "pushes" the layout down and leaves space at the top for the button, but then that space is just filled up by white background color. I also tried adding an alpha = 0 to the outermost FrameLayout to try to avoid this, but it still shows as white background.

I'd appreciate any inputs. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does it have to be a FrameLayout? I use ConstraintLayouts and anchor the FAB to the right and the bottom of the screen and it just floats above everything else.

Comment: Or relativeLayout....

Comment: Either change `android:layout_gravity="top|end"` to `app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"` Or use a `ConstraintLayout` for easy postitioning.

Answer (score 1):

A working example with a ConstraintLayout (this seems much simpler):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @einusername. Is this expected to be in its own xml layout file? I'm just wondering how I can add it to above the bottom sheet that says "delete".

Comment: No, it's the same xml file as yours. Just replace your root layout with a single ConstraintLayout. It's not good to nest them in each other without a reason. app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/deleteTextViewId" would keep it above the textView

Comment: That worked, however, I see a white background color above the textview which is unexpected. It appears like this: https://imgur.com/a/3JUqshI

Comment: Did you put the blue background color on the root ConstraintLayout or is it still in a different layout?

Comment: The white background appears for the button over the textview if the android:background=blue is on the TextView. If the android:background is on the outer ConstraintLayout, the button and textview both have that background. I just want to make it so that the button does not have any background at all and only the TextView has the blue background.

Comment: Maybe there is a mistake in the styles.xml / themes file.